# Changes in functions imported from another Juypter notebook not reflected

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

After importing a function from another jupyter notebook, the changes made in that function are not reflected in the notebook where it is imported. Both notebooks are in same `directory`.

Let's say I have a 2 notebooks - `Notebook_1.ipynb` and `Notebook_2.ipynb` and there be a function `hello_world()` in `Notebook_2.ipynb` -

```
# My Notebook_2.ipynb
def hello_world():
    print('Hello there')
```

Now, I import `hello_world()` in `Notebook_1.ipynb`:

```
# This is Notebook_1
from ipynb.fs.full.Notebook_2 import hello_world
hello_world()
Helloo there
```

Now, let me make a change in `Notebook_2.ipynb` from `Hello there` to `Hello now` and `saved` the file:

```
# My Notebook_2.ipynb
def hello_world():
    print('Hello now')
```

I read [`here`](https://support.enthought.com/hc/en-us/articles/204469240-Jupyter-IPython-After-editing-a-module-changes-are-not-effective-without-kernel-restart) that the since the module is already imported, so it confuses the python and it doesn't reload it. So, one way is to restart the kernel, but then we may lose other information. Another way is to use `importlib.reload(Notebook_2.ipynb)`. I did that, but I still got `Hello there` and not `Hello now`. After waiting for 5 minutes, I got `Hello now`.

```
importlib.reload(ipynb.fs.full.Notebook_2)
hello_world()
Helloo there
```

How to address this issue, so that the updated function is immediately reflected?